# sudo: PAM account management error: Permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, pam

I'm trying connect a Linux machine to AD and I made some changes in some files below:

`/etc/krb5.conf`

`/etc/pam.d/system-auth`

`/etc/samba/smb.conf`

After these changes I connected the server to AD with `net ads join` command. But then users in the sudoers file cannot do `sudo`. The error is:

```
sudo -i
sudo: PAM account management error: Permission denied
```

in `/etc/ssh/sshd` file, UsePAM is no.
and I appanded the line `+:ALL:ALL` to `/etc/security/access.conf`

`/var/log/secure` output:

```
sudo: PAM (sudo-i) illegal module type: %PAM-1.0
sudo: PAM (sudo-i) no control flag supplied
sudo: PAM (sudo-i) no module name supplied
sudo: PAM (sudo-i) illegal module type: %PAM-1.0
sudo: PAM (sudo-i) no control flag supplied
sudo: PAM (sudo-i) no module name supplied
sudo: PAM (sudo-i) illegal module type: %PAM-1.0
sudo: PAM (sudo-i) no control flag supplied
sudo: PAM (sudo-i) no module name supplied
sudo: PAM (sudo-i) illegal module type: %PAM-1.0
sudo: PAM (sudo-i) no control flag supplied
sudo: PAM (sudo-i) no module name supplied
sudo: myuser : PAM account management error: Permission denied ; TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/myuser ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/bash
```

How can I give sudo permission again to my user?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned making changes to `/etc/pam.d/system-auth` (which should be a link to `/etc/pam.d/system-auth-ac`)... have you tried adding `no_access_check` after the first occurrence of `account  sufficient   pam_vas3.so`?

```
# cat system-auth-ac
...
account sufficient  pam_vas3.so no_access_check
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use SSSD, add user in `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` to allow login in your host:

```
simple_allow_users = ad_login
```

Example:

```
simple_allow_users = svc_nessus
```

Restart SSSD (`systemctl restart sssd`) and try use `sudo` again.